# How to get all products with at least X reviews in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to find all rows where `product_id` has at least 3 reviews (`review_id`).

So for the following example:

```
product_id, review_id
1,   1
1,   2
1,   3
2,   4
3,   5
4,   6
4,   7
4,   8
```

It should return:

```
product_id, review_id
1,   1
1,   2
1,   3
4,   6
4,   7
4,   8
```

These are the queries I've tried:

```
query1 = '''
        SELECT first_value(customer_id), first_value(review_id), first_value(product_id)
        FROM df
        WHERE product_category='Toys' OR product_category='Beauty'
        GROUP BY product_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
'''
```

The above only returns the first result, but when I don't use the `first_value` function, I get an error `"expression 'df.review_id' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.`

```
query1 = '''
        SELECT customer_id, review_id, product_id
        FROM df
        WHERE product_category='Toys' OR product_category='Beauty'
        GROUP BY product_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
'''
```

Comment: Do you want a solution in a pure SQL or any solution in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all your top reviewed items as a separate query and join it back to get the rest of the data

```
SELECT df.* FROM
  df
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM df
    WHERE product_category='Toys' OR product_category='Beauty'
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
  ) interesting
  on df.product_id = interesting.product_id
```

It's the general pattern you need to adopt for grouping/counting and then getting more data about products that are in the group. You can't add more columns to the query that does the grouping, because that splits the groups up into smaller counts, dropping below the threshold. You instead count the occurrences of just the ID, restrict it to only those with a count over some value, and then use that list of interesting IDs to retrieve the rest of the info for those IDs, by joining it back to the table that has all the data

Databases that support analytic queries can do it in one hit, but the query pattern above works on databases that don't support analytics, hence why I tend to use it.

A db that supported analytics could be queried thus:

```
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(partition by product_id) numrev
    FROM df
    WHERE product_category='Toys' OR product_category='Beauty'
  ) interesting
  WHERE numrev >= 5
```

The COUNT(*) OVER() esssentially does the same thing; the database will count each product occurrence and present the count for the product on each row, then the where clause restricts only rows that are above 4 count. Conceive that the group by subquery in the first example is hidden in the background (a partition is a grouping operation) of this example, and the joining is implied (because the counted product id is placed on every row, alongside the real product id to which it relates)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. How can I put it back into a 'normal' format? Right now df.head() gives me `Row(product_id='ABC', customer_id=1, review_id='2', product_id='ABC')` and querrying it gives the error `"Reference 'product_id' is ambiguous, could be: df.product_id, interesting.product_id.;"`

Comment: specify the one you want? They're the same so it doesn't matter which you pick. I edited the query, to be just `select df.* from` that way interesting.product_id isn't put in the result set

Comment: But how do I put it in normal data frame format without the Rows()? I can't do any operations on it because I get `'DataFrame' object has no attribute X`. I can't use `df.product_id.value_counts()` or `df.rename(columns={'product_id': 'blah'})`. I don't understand what format it's in

Comment: Oops, that was a silly question! It was a pyspark data frame and the operations I wanted need a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE d061_Table1(product_id int, review_id int);    
//do inserts


select * from d061_Table1 where product_id IN( select distinct product_id  from 
(select product_id,count(product_id) from d061_Table1
group by product_id
having count(product_id)>=3));
```

output:

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
4   6
4   7
4   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PySpark SQL, you could do

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
#Get num reviews per product
counts = df.groupBy(df.product_id).agg(func.countDistinct(df.review_id).alias('num_reviews'))
#Filter for num reviews >= 3
gt_3_reviews = counts.filter(counts.num_reviews >= 3).select(counts.product_id)
#Join it with the original dataframe and select the required columns
res = df.join(counts, counts.product_id == df.product_id).select(df.product_id,df.review_id)
res.show()
```

or using window functions

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql import Window 
#Select distinct rows from columns needed
dist_df = df.select(df.product_id,df.review_id).distinct()
#Define the window
w = Window.partitionBy(dist_df.product_id)
#Count number of reviews per product with the previously defined window
dist_df = dist_df.withColumn('num_reviews',func.count('*').over(w))
#Filter criteria
res = dist_df.filter(dist_df.num_reviews >= 3).select(dist_df.product_id,dist_df.review_id)
res.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark scala sql

```
val df = Seq((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8)).toDF("product_id", "review_id")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("review")
spark.sql(
  """ with t1( select product_id, review_id , count(*) over(partition by product_id) c1 from review)
    select product_id, review_id  from t1 where c1 >=3
  """).show(false)
```

Results:

```
+----------+---------+
|product_id|review_id|
+----------+---------+
|1         |1        |
|1         |2        |
|1         |3        |
|4         |6        |
|4         |7        |
|4         |8        |
+----------+---------+
```

Using df functions to get the same results

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = Seq((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8)).toDF("product_id", "review_id")
df.withColumn("cn",count('product_id).over(Window.partitionBy('product_id))).filter(" cn>=3 ").drop("cn").show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return all results where the product has at least 3 reviews

Oh my, that's such a fantastic use case for windowed aggregation (which is often a better alternative to `groupBy` followed by `join`).

```
scala> input.show
+----------+---------+
|product_id|review_id|
+----------+---------+
|         1|        1|
|         1|        2|
|         1|        3|
|         2|        4|
|         3|        5|
|         4|        6|
|         4|        7|
|         4|        8|
+----------+---------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val productIds = Window.partitionBy("product_id")
val solution = input
  .withColumn("count", count('*) over productIds)
  .filter('count >= 3) // <-- that's the gist of the solution
  .select('product_id, 'review_id)
scala> solution.show
+----------+---------+
|product_id|review_id|
+----------+---------+
|         1|        1|
|         1|        2|
|         1|        3|
|         4|        6|
|         4|        7|
|         4|        8|
+----------+---------+
```

---

I'm leaving performance comparison of windowed vs simple aggregation (`groupBy` + `join`) as a home exercise :)